# Hot to store sql output to array in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is function:

```
protected function get_answers_with_question_id($id){
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}aysquiz_answers
            WHERE question_id=" . $id;

    $answer = $wpdb->get_results($sql, 'ARRAY_A');

    return $answer;
}
```

Call function:

```
    foreach ($questions_ids as $id) {
        
    $answers2[] = $this->get_answers_with_question_id2($id);
        
    }
```

Actual output:

```
[[{"answer":"1000"}],[{"answer":"1000"}],[{"answer":"1000"}]]
```

I need classic array: array(key=>value,key=>value,key=>value,etc.)

Comment: Array keys are used to identify the value, you cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: On a side note, you can get all results in a single query. Running identical queries in a loop is a performance killer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Really no, how to do it.

Comment: it would be enough to at least extract the numeric values from the object

Answer (score -1):

In terms of performance improvements, you can use the `IN` operator in the query.

Taking the full array, you cancel `implode()` this, taking each of the values in the array, and adding them into a comma separated list, within the brackets in the query.

This should return all the values you would have got from looping through and getting them one by one, but without the overhead:

```
protected function get_answers_with_question_ids($questions_ids){
global $wpdb;

$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}aysquiz_answers
        WHERE question_id IN (" . implode(',', $questions_ids) . ")";

$answer = $wpdb->get_results($sql, 'ARRAY_A');

return $answer;
}
```

This change, and perhaps also not creating an array and just assigning the result directly on `$answers2`, should get you the format you want:

```
$answers2 = $this->get_answers_with_question_ids($questions_ids);

// Should return something like [{"answer":"1000"},{"answer":"1000"},{"answer":"1000"}]?

foreach ($answers2 as $a) {
    echo $a.answer // "1000" x 3
}
```

Consider also looking into securing your SQL queries, with it being integers/ids, it should be fine, though, really you want to be santising and escaping any values you use in queries, **ESPECIALLY**, if the user can adjust the query with their input.